# How to grant all priviledges and permisisons to myself?

Tags: sql-server, privileges

I don't want to create roles and play that way at the moment - just trying to get a Q&D on this. When I execute:

```
grant all to [LameDomain\CoolDude]
```

I get the DB barking that (a) the command is deprecated (kept for compatibility reasons only) and that (b) I can't do this to myself (and that's the real problem). NB, I'm the cool dude in the lame domain.

So, my questions are (in raising order of importance) as follows.

1. What syntax can be used to grant all the privileges to self (one-liner if possible)?
2. If necessary, what's the recommended syntax one should use to grant all to self?
3. What's the current version of the command "grant all to XXX"?

**EDIT**

When I try to follow [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259605%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), I get the error that the user or role doesn't exist in the DB, when I try to execute *sp_addrolemember*. However, when attempting to call *sp_grantdbaccess*, I get that the user already has a name in the DB. WTF?!

Comment: You are attempting to execute the command from the privileged user, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the user to system role `db_owner`. This way the user will have all permissions on the database including `ALTER` and `CREATE` objects.

> Members of the db_owner fixed database role can perform all
>   configuration and maintenance activities on the database.

```
USE_database_name
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'user_name'
GO
```

As for `GRANT ALL` you can still use it but it will give not all permissions. List of permissions that will be granted you can see in documentations on [GRANT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: But how can I grant myself? Is it at all possible?!

Comment: Yes, if you have appropriate permissions, in this case at server level. For example, if your login is in `sysadmin` group. You cannot grant permissions, which you don't have, neither to yourself nor to anybody else. Otherwise, it would be one big threat for server security.

Comment: Sorry, my question was unclear. Is it at all possible to grant all permissions to myself using *grant*, instead of adding my name to a role? I can perform *grant all* on other users, just not on myself...